# double headers in jquery

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm struggling with a `jqgrid` requirement.  I want it to do double headers like this:

[image: UI Mockup]

Is this possible, have one header with another below it with ie min / max values, so like having average temperature and then below that a header with min and max

Comment: seems a decent question to me, so +1 from my side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Take a look at the examples:

http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Click on the last demo:

`Frozen Cols.Group Header(new) --> Group Header - with colspan style`

Then in the code, you will see it is configured like so:

```
 groupHeaders:[
  {startColumnName: 'amount', numberOfColumns: 3, titleText: '<em>Price</em>'},
  {startColumnName: 'closed', numberOfColumns: 2, titleText: 'Shiping'}
  ]
```